# get the parent category ids in magento

Tags: magento

i put the following code into magento base template file `view.phtml`.

$categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
print_r($categories)

with the sample data,when on the `Ottoman` product page,which breadcrumb is

```
 Home / Furniture / Living Room / Ottoman
```

the output is `Array ( [0] => 22 )`  the 22 is `Living Room` id. how to get `Furniture and Living Room`  id. thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
$categories=$_product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    $info = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->load($category)
            ->getParentCategory();
    echo $info->getId(); //display category ID
    //var_dump($info->debug());  # display model contents
}
```

Comment: your code output the id of Furniture not Living Room. is there are way to output both of them.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can get all categories id's:

```
//load root category 
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$rootCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->load($rootCategoryId);

//load all children categories of the root category
$childrenCategories = $rootCategory->getChildrenCategories();
```

Now you can have access to their ids like so:

```
foreach ($childrenCategories as $category) {
        var_dump($category->getId());
}
```

Comment: But this searches only children of root not parents of a category.